# Matlab: How to assign a status when at least a certain value is reached?

Tags: matlab, conditional-statements

I have a matrix like this:

```
A(a,b)=

   NaN     1     1
   NaN     2   NaN
   NaN     3     1
   NaN     4     2
   NaN     5     3
   NaN     6     4
   NaN     7     5
   NaN     8     6
   NaN     9   NaN
   NaN    10   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN     1
   NaN   NaN     2
   NaN   NaN     3
   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

and I would like to obtain a matrix (logical or numerical) where a 1 is assigned to all the values there are not NaN and whenever a certain value, lets say 5, is reached. But (here it comes the difficult part) the 1 has to be assigned also to the numbers before of the 5 (from 1 to 5), again if and only if the 5 is reached.
Therefore, my expected result should be a matrix like the following:

```
B(a,b) = 

0   1   0
0   1   0
0   1   1
0   1   1
0   1   1
0   1   1
0   1   1
0   1   1
0   1   0
0   1   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
```

Some ideas please?
Additional info following the comments:
I am considering the order column wise. Every run of numbers in each column will start always from 1 and continue in the form 1,2,3,...
A NaN will stop this sequence and when it will restart will restart from 1.
If a sequence between two NaN contains the specified value, then all entries have to be true (value=1) between the prior and posterior NaN (see 3rd column as example)

Comment: I don't understand the part with "before of the 5". Could you explain it a bit more? Also try out  `help isnan`.

Comment: Can it be assumed that each run of numbers is always of the form `1, 2, ...`?

Comment: Okay so you consider this column wise. Your numbers start at `1` and increase or are followed by a `nan` and start all over. Iff a sequence between two `nans` contains a specific values, then ALL entries are `true` between the prior and posterior `nan` ?

Comment: Yes, I am considering the order column wise. Every run of numbers in each column will start always from 1 and continue in the form 1,2,3,...
A NaN will stop this sequence and when it will restart will restart with 1.
Yes,  If a sequence between two nans contains the specified value, then all entries have to be true (value=1) between the prior and posterior nan

Comment: Many thanks guys, I tried both your approaches and they both work perfectly. I decided to adopt the one proposed by @sonystarmap because it resulted to be faster (0.020s against 0.358s) and more intuitive to me. Thank you again.

Comment: It might also be possible to increase the stride of the inner loop.  `i=1(k-2):n ` should also work, however I didn't check it for any other cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is not very efficient but does the job. If you need an efficient code, something else might be more suitable. However, this does the trick:

```
function stackoverflow

A =[

NaN     1     1
NaN     2   NaN
NaN     3     1
NaN     4     2
NaN     5     3
NaN     6     4
NaN     7     5
NaN     8     6
NaN     9   NaN
NaN    10   NaN
NaN   NaN   NaN
NaN   NaN     1
NaN   NaN     2
NaN   NaN     3
NaN   NaN   NaN];


[n,m] = size(A);

k= 5;
B =(A>=k);

for j=1:m % for all rows
    for i=1:n % for all columns
        if B(i,j)==1 % if the value is >=5, all 4 prior values also have to be 1
            B(i-(k-1):i,j) =1;
        end
    end
end

disp(A)
disp(B)
```

But I'm pretty sure, that there is a way to get rid of the loop(s), which I can't figure out right now.

Answer (score 1):

Let your data matrix be defined as

```
A = [NaN     1     1
     NaN     2   NaN
     NaN     3     1
     NaN     4     2
     NaN     5     3
     NaN     6     4
     NaN     7     5
     NaN     8     6
     NaN     9   NaN
     NaN    10   NaN
     NaN   NaN   NaN
     NaN   NaN     1
     NaN   NaN     2
     NaN   NaN     3
     NaN   NaN   NaN];
```

Here's one approach using regular expressions to detect runs of at least 5 numeric values:

```
B = mat2cell(char(~isnan(A).'+'0'),ones(size(A,2),1)); %'// make a string from each column
C = regexprep(B, '(1{5}1*)', '${repmat(''+'',1,numel($0))}'); %// change that 5 as needed
result = vertcat(C{:}).'=='+';
```

This gives

```
result =
     0     1     0
     0     1     0
     0     1     1
     0     1     1
     0     1     1
     0     1     1
     0     1     1
     0     1     1
     0     1     0
     0     1     0
     0     0     0
     0     0     0
     0     0     0
     0     0     0
     0     0     0
```